# Session gets clear in category page only in Magento

Tags: magento, session, cookies, session-cookies, categories

I have one problem in Magento Liver server uploaded site.
The problem is related to session or cookies. When I add product to cart or login, then visit category page, the session gets clear and i get signout and cart gets clear.

I tried setting session/cookie management. but not found solution.
Also asked to server technical support, they also not able to found.
This only happens in only one page category page.

Any other had faced this problem.

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for session issue fix

https://www.creare.co.uk/session-error-in-magento

Comment: Thanks for answer. We changed hosting server. It was server problem.